# How would I find the P-Value of this data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, p-value

I have the following data (relating to consecutive months at current job):

- Mean: 45.4
- Standard Deviation: 60.89
- Sample Size: 48

I am asked to do a one-tailed test at a 1% significance level and provide:

1. the value of the test statistic (from above).
2. P-Value of the test statistic.

My initial assumption about the data is that most of the values would fall under 60 months. With that said, my hypothesis is:

H<sub>0</sub>: x̄ ≤ 60, H<sub>a</sub>: x̄ > 60

How do I proceed with this problem? I am not sure I understand the process.

Thank you

Comment: *Data* doesn't have a p-value. A p-value is associated with the test statistic in a particular *hypothesis test*. So start by working out which particular hypothesis and alternative you might be dealing with and which hypothesis test goes with it. It looks like a one-sample test of means might be required, but it's not at *all* clear what the hypothesized mean might be. Did you leave information out?

Comment: Since this appears to be routine bookwork, it appears to fall under the `self-study` tag. Please add the tag and read its [tag wiki info](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info), and if necessary, adding information to your question according to what it asks for. In short - what *can* you do/ what do you understand, and what have you tried?  (A response of "nothing" would suggest you need to avail yourself of other resources first, such as remedial tutoring)

Comment: I have a hypothesis I did not include, which I will add to the question. Also, I will add that tag. I am currently working through examples, however, they do not appear to be in the same context as this particular problem. That is why I am attempting to find an explanation for this specific scenario.

Comment: Hypotheses are not about sample quantities ($\bar x$) but population quantities. If it was about $\bar x$ you wouldn't need to test it, you'd just look at the sample mean and compare it with 60! It's because population quantities are unobserved that you need to worry about statistical inference for them (inferring information about them from samples).

Comment: Some related questions with helpful information anent this situation can be found with a [search](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=student+t+test+[self-study]).